# c++ variables in different block scopes has same addresses

Tags: c++, g++

In below code #3 and #4 print same address of 'int i'
Could anyone describe how this works?
It happens in some g++ not in vc++, clang

```
#include <iostream>

int i = 0;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "#1: " << &i << std::endl;

    {
        int i;
        std::cout << "#2: " << &i << std::endl;

        {
            int i;
            std::cout << "#3: " << &i << std::endl;
        }

        {
            int i;
            std::cout << "#4: " << &i << std::endl;

            {
                int i;
                std::cout << "#5: " << &i << std::endl;
            }
       }
    }
}
```

and if I run above code the result is like below

```
#1: 0x601194
#2: 0x7ffc027b5154
#3: 0x7ffc027b515c
#4: 0x7ffc027b5158
#5: 0x7ffc027b515c
```

Comment: Do you mean #3 and #5 are the same? And what's weird with that?

Comment: `local variable ... in block scope` That's redundant by the way. The term "local variable" refers to variables that are declared in block scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could anyone describe how this works?

After a variable is destroyed (for automatic storage variable it happens when their block ends) its memory can be reused again. So that what you see there - `i` on case #3 gets destroyed as it's block terminates and that memory reused again later (in this case it happens that `i` from #5 reuses the same memory).